# Change tags in symbol Pattern/Matcher

Tags: java, regex

This code works fine :

```
final String result = myString.replaceAll("<tag1>", "{").replaceAll("<tag2>", "}");
```

but I have to parse big files, so I'm asking me if I can have a `Pattern.compile("REGEX");` before the `while` :

```
Patter p = Pattern.compile("REGEX");
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
     final String myWorkLine = scan.readLine();
     p.matcher(s).replaceAll("$1"); // or other value
     ..;
}
```

I expect faster result because regex compilation is maid once and only once.

*EDIT*

I want to put (if it is possible) the `replaceAll(..).replaceAll(..)` model in a Pattern, and have `tag1`==>`{`, and `tag2`==>`}`.

Question : is *outside loop* `Pattern` model faster than *inside loop* `replaceAll.replaceAll` model?

Comment: What do you need exactly? Is it that you need all `<tag1>` and `<tag2>` to be replaced with `{` and `}` respectively?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your original question: yes, you could do that, and indeed it would be faster than your original code, if you apply the *same* regular expression(s) multiple times in a loop. Your loop should be rewritten like this:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("REGEX1");
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("REGEX1");
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String myWorkLine = scan.readLine();
    myWorkLine = p1.matcher(myWorkLine).replaceAll("replacement1");
    myWorkLine = p2.matcher(myWorkLine).replaceAll("replacement2");
    ...;
}
```

But, if your're not using regular expressions, as your first example suggests (`"<tag1>"`), then don't use `String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`, as it is slower because of the regular expression. Instead use `String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`, as it doesn't work with regular expression and is much faster.

Example:

```
"ABAP is fun! ABAP ABAP ABAP".replace("ABAP", "Java");
```

See: [Java Docs for String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

It's not nice changing your question that radically, but ok, here again an answer for your regular expression:

```
String s1
       = "You can <bold>have nice weather</bold>, but <bold>not</bold> always!";
//EDIT: the regex was 'overengineered', and .?? should have been .*?
//String s2 = s1.replaceAll("(.*?)<bold>(.*?)</bold>(.??)", "$1{$2}$3");
String s2 = s1.replaceAll("<bold>(.*?)</bold>", "{$1}");

System.out.println(s2);
```

Output: `You can {have nice weather}, but {not} always!`

Here the loop with this new regex, and yes, this would be faster than original loop:

```
//EDIT: the regex was 'overengineered'
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<bold>(.*?)</bold>");
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String myWorkLine = scan.readLine();
    myWorkLine = p.matcher(myWorkLine).replaceAll("{$1}");
    ...;
}
```

EDIT:
Here the description of [Java RegEx syntax constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)

Comment: Thanks for your patience - I've not found the good writing the first time. The last regex in Pattern works fine and it is exactly what I've searched without result. [I did not know the "(.??)"]

Comment: You're welcome.
OMG, that "`.??`" was a mistake, stupid me. Should have been "`.*?`". I corrected it. And OMG OMG I overcomplicated the regex! The before/after matching groups are necessary only when working with `^` and `$` (i.e. begin/end of line). I edited & simplified the examples, and added a link to Java regex definitions. Sorry.

Comment: No stupid : make mistakes and forget them is human stuff, correct home made is master eyes signature. With such a mistake, I believe you have definitively give me the keys to understand 'special constructs regex'; and it is me THE stupid, not able to find the final solution, so simple  - ich danke Ihnen sehr.

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` uses regex Patterns. From the java.lang.String [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html):

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement);
}
```

**Edit1:** Please stop changing what you're asking. Pick a question and stick with it.

**Edit2:**

If you're really sure you want to do it this way, compiling a regex outside of the loop, in the simplest case you'd need two different patterns:

```
Pattern tag1Pattern = Pattern.compile("<tag1>");
Pattern tag2Pattern = Pattern.compile("<tag2>");
while( scan.hasNextLine() ) {
    String line = scan.readLine();
    String modifiedLine = tag1Pattern.matcher(line).replaceAll("{");
    modifiedLine = tag2Pattern.matcher(line).replaceAll("}");
    ...
}
```

You're still applying the pattern matcher twice per line, so if there's any performance hits that's why.

Without knowing what your data looks like, it's hard to give you a more precise answer or better regex. Unless you've edited your question (again) while I was writing this.

Comment: My problem is to find the good "REGEX" inside the Pattern.compile to make two different replacements.